# useFocusEffect cleanup happens after next page useEffect?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I noticed a counter-intuitive behaviour with useFocusEffect cleanup.

I have a Page1 with useFocusEffect & its cleanup -> it navigates to Page2 with a useEffect.
In the code below, I expect to see in the logs `1, 2, 3` but I actually see `1, 3, 2`.

**The cleanup of Page1 is triggered after the useEffect of Page2.**

```js
const Page1 = () => {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  useFocusEffect(() => {
    console.log('1');
    return () => {
      console.log('2');
    };
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => navigate('PAGE2')} title="Go to Page2" />
    </View>
  );
};

const Page2 = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('3');
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

See [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@mldddd/react-navigation-v5-lifecycle) (you can see the logs by clicking the bottom bar).

Is this normal? I can't seem to find an explanation in the docs.

Is there a way to trigger the cleanup #2 before the useEffect #3?

Comment: For me it behave as expected -> https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/react-navigation-v5-lifecycle
Log: 2 should be executed after Log: 4

Comment: @MichaelBahl I'm not very familiar with `useFocusEffect`, I thought it would behave the same way a `useEffect` behave for a re-render. IE (correct me if I'm wrong) cleanup 1st render THEN effects of 2nd render.

Is there a way to do some cleanup on Page1 before running the effects of Page2?

Comment: I don‘t know if that is possible. Why is it so necessary to run a cleanup before open new screen?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Trying to update some analytics so I want to clear them in the first cleanup function, then set new ones in the second. Because of this behavior it sets new attributes, and then clears them all with the cleanup function.